# extraxt text and save it in a variable using python

Tags: python, parsing, graphviz

I have a text file containing debug info, what I am interested in are lines like

```
__kmp_task_alloc(exit): T#0 created task 0xf67980 parent=0xe59580
__kmp_task_alloc(exit): T#2 created task 0x7f5b30100900 parent=0xf67980
```

I need to save T#0, T#2 or whatever T# number is every time a task is created based on the keyword "created task" 
I am not familiar with Python but since I have to use graphviz I  am using it.

following some examples I tried to do this

```
           file  = open("fib5.txt","r")
           lines = file.readlines()
           file.close()
           i=0
           #lock for pattern
           for line in lines:
               #print (line)    
               m = re.search('T#(.+?)created task', line)
                  if m:
                        found = m.group(1)

           print (found)
```

I always get the result 1 even that there are 44 hits in the text file.

Comment: You're trying to take group 5, but you should be looking for group 1.

Comment: yea , but that was for exploring , I'll fix the question , Thanks!

Comment: I assumed that was your problem because it was a problem and you didn't specify. What is actually going wrong?

Comment: it always prints 1 even that the text file has 44 hits

Comment: Indent the `print(found)` line until it's actually in the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes because your `print` is outside the `for` loop and it is printing the last value of `found`.

Comment: yes, you are right! thanks... now I feel embarrassed should I keep the question or delete it

Answer (score 0):

my print was not included in the for loop

```
file  = open("fib5.txt","r")
       lines = file.readlines()
       file.close()
       i=0
       #lock for pattern
       for line in lines:
           #print (line)    
           m = re.search('T#(.+?)created task', line)
              if m:
                    found = m.group(1)

                    print (found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reworked your code:

```
with open('fib5.txt', 'r') as f:
lines = f.read()
m = re.findall('T#(.+?)created task', lines)

for x in m:
    print(x)
```

It's a good practise to open file using **with** keyword. [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

You don't need to scan file line by line. In re module there is a function **findall** which is returning all matches of pattern. [Finding all Adverbs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs)